# Getting Wine error after upgrade from 16.10 to 17.04

Tags: wine, 17.04

After upgraded to 17.04 i am sadly getting this error when i try to run my AmigaForever via wine:

```
env WINEPREFIX="/home/elan/.wine" wine AmigaForever.exe or wine AmigaForever.exe

wine client error:0: version mismatch 524/490.
Your wine binary was not upgraded correctly,
or you have an older one somewhere in your PATH.
Or maybe the wrong wineserver is still running?
```

Any ideas how to fix this guys?

Comment: Which of those three possibilities is it?

Answer (score 1):

I'd definitely recommend uninstalling wine and reinstalling it. it's quite insane to expect wine (and it's app) to work past a distribution upgrade. plus the error message seems to confirm it's a version error.

```
sudo apt --purge remove wine
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

At this point you can decide whether you want to conserve your  AmigaForever install or re-run a clean install. I say you stand to loose nothing by doing it if you go into your `.wine` folder and collect your save files first (if such a thing even exists for this program. From what I'm googleling, there doesn't even seem to be that option) (and you really should do the clean reinstall because if you do it'll run alot better).

So go into your home folder (with file browser) hit `Ctrl-H`
This will reveal hiddin files, files starting with a `.`
The folder `.wine` is where you wanna go and from there it's windows-only so not my nor ask-ubuntu turf but you should know what to copy to another folder temporarily like `home/elanozturk/documents`.

Once this is done you can now delete all wine files completely (again if you aren't re-running the amiga forever install skip this step) :

```
rm -r "$HOME/.wine"
rm  $HOME/.config/menus/applications-merged/wine*
rm -r "$HOME/.local/share/applications/wine"
rm $HOME/.local/share/desktop-directories/wine*
rm $HOME/.local/share/icons/????_*.xpm
```

Back to the main course don't skip the following this is to reinstall wine :

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
wget https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key
sudo apt-key add Release.key
sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
```

Now if you've deleted wine/amiga forver you can re-run your amiga forver installer then (after testing that it runs correctly) go back into the `.wine` folder and put the files back.

Cheers! tell me if this works.